How to integrate html or json report in test cafe
Unable to generate html or json report in test cafe
Followed these steps
npm install testcafe-reporter-json
testcafe chrome 'path/to/test/file.js' --reporter json

But unable to generate.
I have tried all possible ways

Please provide more information and the code inside the file.js file
